# Restful-web-services - calling function with parameter

Tags: rest

I need to call function from restful web  service which have complex parameter class from. How can I call function with parameter? I'm using mvc 3 for my restful web service and application that is calling it. This is code for calling web service's function :

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);           
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

How can I pass parameter to function?
Thx

Comment: Can you give some more details? May be technology you are going to use?